# Is there a better way to combine multiple types of selector i.e name, class and :not?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to attach a event listener on few DOM element with a certain class but without some exception class.

```
$("body").on('change', 
    'select.action:not(.disabled), 
    textarea.action:not(.disabled), 
    input[type=\'text\'].action:not(.disabled)', 

    function() {
        //... 
    }
);
```

I am just wondering if there would be a better way to write this, as the elements to which I want the event listener to listen to might grow. Something like this:

```
$("body").on('change', '(select, textarea, input[type=\'text\']).action:not(.disabled)', 
    function() {
        //... 
    }
);
```

Also, I don't want to filter the elements after attaching to a more general.

*Note:* I am not filtering as `.action:not(.disabled)` is because I only want to attach to some specific elements and not all. The reason behind this is there are other event listeners on similar elements for other events such as `click` and `mouseenter`.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `.action:not(.disabled)`  or maybe to be more specific `:input.action:not(.disabled)`? BTW, I'm wondering why instead don't you try to target specific elements instead of not targeting list of elements?!

Comment: @A.Wolff, I want to listen to only certain element

Comment: So why not use selector to target these specific elements, using a class for example. I guess if you post relevant HTML markup, there is better way to do this. Maybe i'm out of topic but it is hard to figure it out without seeing concrete sample

Comment: @A.Wolff, I have added a note, may be it will be of some help.

Comment: To answer to your `why instead don't you try to target specific elements instead of not targeting list of elements?`. Its because the elements are dynamic and can and/or cannot trigger the underlying function.

Answer (score 2):

You can just drop the element selector:

```
$("body").on("change", ".action:not(.disabled)", function() { ... });
```

This will select all elements with a `.action` class and no `.disabled` class.

> I dont want to attach in all, hence I define them.

In that case you can either filter it further by adding additional `:not()` statements or stick with what you have already. jQuery will ultimately pass these selectors into JavaScript's native `document.querySelectorAll()` method, so a single comma-delimited string of selectors would be the most performant method.

For instance, if you don't want to target `span` elements, you can specify: `:not(span)`.

Comment: what if a password field is with class `.action` ?

Comment: I dont want to attach in all, hence I define them.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy then all you'd simply add `:not([type=password])` to the end.

Comment: @Starx you can either look at my above comment or stick with what you have already. jQuery ultimately will pass these selectors into JavaScript's native `querySelectorAll` method, so a single comma-delimited string would be the most performant method. I've updated my answer to include this.